# Using transitions for fading in elements in ReactJS

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm working on animating one of my pages, a testimonials page that has multiple body elements to it. I had the idea to fade in each one of the body elements one by one using [this tutorial](https://reactjs.org/docs/animation.html). The thing I'm confused about is where the example code contains this:

```
return (
  <div>
    <button onClick={this.handleAdd}>Add Item</button>
    <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
      transitionName="example"
      transitionEnterTimeout={500}
      transitionLeaveTimeout={300}>

      {items} // this specifically
    </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
  </div>
```

Would I have to add each one of the body elements to a list of items in order to get this to work? I'm pretty confused about how I should go about doing this. My first thought would be to wrap each one of the body elements into their own separate `ReactCSSTransitionGroup`, like such:

```
 <ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
    <body className="testimonial-body" id="placeholder">
        <p>"This is another testimonial. This will probably contain
            information such as how good his work was and stuff like that.
            Blah blah blah blah blahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh."
            <span class="testimonial-signature">- Some random dude &sdot; Somwhere, Anywhere</span>
        </p>
        <Gallery images={doug_and_sue_images} // will change
                 backdropClosesModal={true}
                 enableKeyboardInput={true}
                 enableImageSelection={false}/> 
    </body>
  </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
```

But that doesn't seem right because I don't know what I would replace `{items}` with. Below is the code I'm working with:

```
import React from 'react';
import '../Client/CSS/Testimonials.css'
import Gallery from 'react-grid-gallery'
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-transition-group';

const doug_and_sue_images =
[{
        src: "https://c2.staticflickr.com/9/8817/28973449265_07e3aa5d2e_b.jpg",
        thumbnail: "https://c2.staticflickr.com/9/8817/28973449265_07e3aa5d2e_n.jpg",
        thumbnailWidth: 320,
        thumbnailHeight: 174,
        caption: "After Rain (Jeshu John - designerspics.com)"
},
{
        src: "https://c2.staticflickr.com/9/8356/28897120681_3b2c0f43e0_b.jpg",
        thumbnail: "https://c2.staticflickr.com/9/8356/28897120681_3b2c0f43e0_n.jpg",
        thumbnailWidth: 320,
        thumbnailHeight: 212,
        caption: "Boats (Jeshu John - designerspics.com)"
},

{
        src: "https://c4.staticflickr.com/9/8887/28897124891_98c4fdd82b_b.jpg",
        thumbnail: "https://c4.staticflickr.com/9/8887/28897124891_98c4fdd82b_n.jpg",
        thumbnailWidth: 320,
        thumbnailHeight: 212
}]

class Testimonials extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>See what people are saying...</h2>
                <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
                    transitionName="example"
                    transitionAppear={true}
                    transitionAppearTimeout={500}
                    transitionEnter={false}
                    transitionLeave={false}>
                    <body className="testimonial-body" id="doug_and_sue">
                        <p>"Dependable, trustworthy, and expert workmanship all 
                           describe Kevin and his business.  
                           He completely transformed our condo, painting it from top to 
                           bottom, among other projects.
                           Not only does he do excellent work, but he's a 
                           pleasure to have in your home. For any future projects, 
                           there's no one we'd rather have than Kevin." 
                           <span class="testimonial-signature"> - Doug and Sue &sdot; Brookfield, WI</span>
                        </p>
                        <Gallery images={doug_and_sue_images} 
                                 backdropClosesModal={true}
                                 enableKeyboardInput={true}
                                 enableImageSelection={false}/>
                    </body>
                </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
                <body className="testimonial-body" id="placeholder">
                    <p>"This is another testimonial. This will probably contain
                        information such as how good his work was and stuff like that.
                        Blah blah blah blah blahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh."
                        <span class="testimonial-signature">- Some random dude &sdot; Somwhere, Anywhere</span>
                    </p>
                    <Gallery images={doug_and_sue_images} // will change
                             backdropClosesModal={true}
                             enableKeyboardInput={true}
                             enableImageSelection={false}/> 
                </body>
                <body className="testimonial-body" id="placeholder">
                    <p>"This is another testimonial. This will probably contain
                        information such as how good his work was and stuff like that.
                        Blah blah blah blah blahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh."
                        <span class="testimonial-signature">- Some random dude &sdot; Somwhere, Anywhere</span>
                    </p>
                    <Gallery images={doug_and_sue_images} // will change
                             backdropClosesModal={true}
                             enableKeyboardInput={true}
                             enableImageSelection={false}/> 
                </body>
                <body className="testimonial-body" id="placeholder">
                    <p>"This is another testimonial. This will probably contain
                        information such as how good his work was and stuff like that.
                        Blah blah blah blah blahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh."
                        <span class="testimonial-signature">- Some random dude &sdot; Somwhere, Anywhere</span>
                    </p>
                    <Gallery images={doug_and_sue_images} // will change
                             backdropClosesModal={true}
                             enableKeyboardInput={true}
                             enableImageSelection={false}/> 
                </body>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Testimonials;
```

CSS:

```
h2 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-style: italic;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

body {
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
}

.testimonial-body p {
    font-size: 16pt;
    font-style: italic;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
}

span.testimonial-signature {
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 1%;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

/* transitions */
.example-enter {
    opacity: 0.01;
}

.example-enter.example-enter-active {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 500ms ease-in;
}

.example-leave {
    opacity: 1;
}

.example-leave.example-leave-active {
    opacity: 0.01;
    transition: opacity 300ms ease-in;
}

.example-appear {
    opacity: 0.01;
  }

.example-appear.example-appear-active {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
}

/* Mobile View */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .testimonial-body p {
        font-size: 14pt;
    }
}
```